# Specflow autogenerated file is not nested with feature file and steps aren't bound

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, specflow

I'm using VS 2017, Specflow 2.4.1, and MSBuild.

When creating a new feature file the autogenerated file is being generated, I can see it in the project folder and in the solution when hidden files are displayed. For some reason it's not apart of the solution and won't bundle with the feature. If I manually add it to the project and rebuild it will show in the test explorer, but the steps aren't bound. I've cleared the temp folder and the stepmap has been regenerated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: File generated but not included in solution]

[image: Manually added and shows in test explorer]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the "Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator CustomTool" option in Visual Studio set to `True`:

[image: Screenshot of VS options showing SpecFlow settings]

You can access this from Tools > Options > SpecFlow.

You might need to exclude that feature file from the project, delete the feature.cs file for it, and then re-include that feature file before the problem is fixed.

Comment: It should be set to false when using the MSBuild tool, which is stated in Specflow documentation - https://specflow.org/documentation/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild/. the file is generating as well, just not nested or included in the solution.

Comment: @sysofadown3: not for SpecFlow 2. They switched to MS Build generation in SpecFlow 3. The OP said they are using SpecFlow 2.4, so they will need this set to true.